# Rebless a Perl Moose base class instance to a subclass

Tags: perl, inheritance, moose

(I think) I want to be able to convert a base class instance into a subclass. I haven't tried tackling this as a role, but subclassing feels better for my situation. I get a compilation error when I try to override a method. It seems to be related to my use-ing my subclass in the base class.

**Tank.pm**

```
package Tank;

use Moose;
use Tank::Forecast;

has id => (
    isa      => 'Int',
    is       => 'ro',
    required => 1,
);

sub make_forecast {
    my $self = shift;
    my $date = shift;

    return Tank::Forecast->meta->rebless_instance( $self, date => $date );
}

1;
```

**Tank/Forecast.pm**

```
    package Tank::Forecast;

    use Moose;

    extends 'Tank';

    has date => (
        isa      => 'Str',
        is       => 'ro',
        required => 1,
    );

    has end_volume => (
        isa     => 'Num',
        is      => 'ro',
        default => sub { rand() },
    );

    override 'make_forecast' => sub {
        my $self = shift;

        Tank->meta->rebless_instance_back($self);

        return super();
    };
  1;
```

**test.pl**

```
use Tank;

my $tank = Tank->new( id => 1 );
$tank->make_forecast('2019-06-27');
print $tank->end_volume . "\n";
$tank->make_forecast('2019-06-28');
print $tank->end_volume . "\n";
```

This generates a compilation error:

```
You cannot override 'make_forecast' because it has no super method at /home/carl/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/site_perl/5.16.3/i686-linux/Moose/Exporter.pm line 419
    Moose::override('make_forecast', 'CODE(0x1871e70)') called at Tank/Forecast.pm line 25
    require Tank/Forecast.pm at Tank.pm line 4
    Tank::BEGIN at Tank/Forecast.pm line 0
    eval {...} at Tank/Forecast.pm line 0
    require Tank.pm at test.pl line 1
    main::BEGIN at Tank/Forecast.pm line 0
    eval {...} at Tank/Forecast.pm line 0
Compilation failed in require at Tank.pm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Tank.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at test.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 1.
```

I am open to suggestions on the best way to design this and have it actually work.

**EDIT:** My code appears to work when I remove the Moose override/super sugar.  I do feel like my code doesn't pass the smell test, so I'll wait for a better answer before I post this change as an answer.

```
sub make_forecast {
    my $self = shift;

    # This removes existing Forecast attributes
    Tank->meta->rebless_instance_back($self);

    return $self->SUPER::make_forecast(@_);
```

}

**EDIT:** It appears that I need to describe my project more. I have tanks that are represented with general attributes such as location, name, capacity, current level, etc. I have a need for creating forecasts for a specific day. I feel like I want all of this in a single class, but I don't want to pollute the standard tank class with forecasting stuff. Adding a role, either statically or dynamically, was not quit right. I thought converting a tank object to a tank with a forecast object would work, which is what created the error described in this post. I've also toyed with making the forecast class discrete from the tank and using delegation to it from the tank instance, but that just seems a little clunkier. Sigh. I hope this helps. I'm still trying to figure out the best design for this and really appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: You have a cyclic dependency here. `Tank` loads `Tank::Forecast`, and `Tank::Forecast` loads `Tank`. In general, base classes should not know about their subclasses. I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It is not clear why you would need the `rebless_instance()` and `rebless_instance_back()`. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Hakon I should have put a comment there. That is there so that I can convert a Forecast instance to different one. Reblessing back would ensure that all off the original subclass attributes would be removed. In production, I'd probably clone it to a new instance.

Comment: @melpomene I'm sure you're right. Do you have a good way of accomplishing my goal? My code seemed to be working before I put the override in, but I suspect it was broken and I just didn't know it.

Comment: Well, what is your goal?